# String Letter Converted on 0

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program (on VB) to Copy a especific Folder from an USB, but whatever that I Use (TextBox, ComboBox, ListBox), always the DriveR Letter (C: for test) is converted to a 0, so te program doesn't works. If I Use another Dim...As.., like Integer, I get the "*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll*" Error

here is my Code:

```
Private Sub RespJ_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RespJ.Click
    Dim CarpetaI, CarpetaL, ID As String
    Dim Letra As Integer
    Letra = Val(combobox1.Text)
    ID = Val(IDTB.Text)
    CarpetaI = Letra + ":\WPSystem\AppData\" + ID
    CarpetaL = "C:\RespaldoWP\WPSystem\AppData\" + ID
    Label1.Text = CarpetaI
    'My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(CarpetaL)
    'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(CarpetaI, CarpetaL, True)
End Sub
```

*The last 2 lines are commented because I want to test the Code (Using a label to see if the path is correct) before to make it copy/past on real/testing files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

Your variable should be a `String`:

`Dim Letra As String`

Don't use the [`Val` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to read the drive letter from the combo box:

`Letra = combobox1.Text`